# Arbitrary type casting in C++

Tags: c++, casting

I have a series of bytes coming in across a transport medium (one byte at a time) that I need to reconstitute into a message structure. The two ends share a common header file in which the message structure is `packed`. Both ends are also compiled using the same compiler, though it should not matter given the packing attribute. This is simple in C, but I must fit this code into a larger code-base written in C++. I have tried playing around with various modes of casting in C++, but I can't seem to properly use them.

I have been writing embedded firmware in C for a while, but have mostly only read C++ code. So, what is the "proper" way to do something like this in C++? Assuming `recv_msg` is a callback function that is executed when a new byte is available to be read:

```
void recv_msg(uint8_t data)
{
    static int bytes_recvd = 0;
    static struct msg = {0};

    ((uint8_t*)&msg)[bytes_recvd] = data;
    if(++bytes_recvd == sizeof(struct msg)){
        printf("Msg received\n");
        bytes_recvd = 0;
        g_msg_recvd_flag = 1;
    }
}
```

The problem I am running into is the strict typing of C++ not allowing me to make an arbitrary cast of `msg` into an array of `uint8_t`. Such a thing makes it *very* simple to reconstruct the message struct one byte at a time.

Assuming I have `bytes_recvd` and `struct msg` as members of a related C++ class, how can something analogous be done in C++?

Comment: Using `std::memcpy` is the "safe" way to do this.

Comment: Why are the local variables `static`? And why don't you return anything?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I just threw this code together as I was writing this question. I edited it a bit. `static` is common in firmware, especially when you find the callback being executed asynchronously when triggered by an external interrupt. Static is great for tracking state -- in this case the number of bytes so far received. There may be another component of the firmware waiting for `g_msg_recvd_flag` to be set before going off and parsing/using it for something. This is like top and bottom halves in the Linux kernel, if you are familiar.

Comment: You cannot cast a struct to a pointer. Maybe you want to cast the _address_ of `msg` to `uint8_t`? `reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&msg)` would be the most idiomatic C++.

Comment: You are simply missing a `&` before `msg` after the cast. There's nothing C++ specific here, it wouldn't work exactly the same in C.

Comment: Unless you need to keep a value between calls `static` is not needed. And even then there are usually better solutions (even if they involve global variables!). And don't just "throw" some code together, put some thought inti your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: AFAICT the state being kept around is the message being constructed; `recv_msg` is intended a bit like an interrupt handler for "a byte has been received". Of course in "saner" (and more generic code) you'd have a context pointer or something like that not to limit the callback to operate on a single message.

Comment: C style casts all still work in C++.  C++ adds more cast syntax that helps to avoid programmer errors

Comment: @Justin `memcpy` is equivalent to a series of character assignments . OP code is attempting to do a series of character assignments; there is nothing to be gained by somehow using memcpy

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, The state is the number of bytes received. The struct does not need to be static in this example, as I could be writing off to some globally scope address, sure. It all depends on how the code is architected. This may work by executing `memcpy` after all bytes are received, but I did not fully write all of that as it was not relevant to the question. This example is complete insofar as information is available that is needed to answer the question.

Comment: @MatteoItalia msg might be a wrapper for a char array.

Comment: @Cppplus1: as long as it's a "regular", C-style `struct` with no particular operator overloading or implicit casts, the specific content is completely irrelevant; if instead you throw that in the mix, it depends from exactly what implicit casts/operator you implement.

Comment: The solution has been quietly edited into the question. I'm voting to close as unclear since this question makes no sense now

Comment: @MatteoItalia, Geeze. Thanks all. It indeed was a simple missing ampersand in this case. I have not worked often enough with C++ compilers I suppose. I didn't recognize what the output error was describing. I edited the post, but included a note in the edit summary.

Answer (score 1):

Use `unsigned char` instead of `uint8_t`, and you'll avoid strict aliasing violation.

`unsigned char` can be used for read/modify any object: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

> Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an
>   object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the
>   behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true:
>
> [...]
>
> AliasedType is std::byte, (since C++17)char, or **unsigned char: this
>   permits examination of the object representation of any object as an
>   array of bytes.**

So use this:

`reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&msg)[bytes_recvd] = data;`

Comment: I wonder if there's any way to have an `uint8_t` that is not a `typedef` for `unsigned char`... the standard mandates `CHAR_BITS` to be at least 8 (but not smaller). OTOH, there can be no type smaller than `unsigned char`, since its size is 1 by definition (i.e., it corresponds to the granularity of the address space). So, either you don't have `uint8_t` period (e.g. on a DSP whose minimum data type size is 16 bit), or it must be of the same size as `unsigned char`. Still, I think it's technically possible for an implementation to provide it as an identical but distinct type.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<uint8_t> max
```

or

```
uint8_t msg[max_data]
```

and then you can use the assignment operator
msg[bytes_recvd] = data